# Does "launch our own idea" mean "provide our own ideas"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Does "***launch our own idea***" mean "***provide our own ideas***" ?

I found this can mean send or begin but I think here it means provide idea.
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/launch

> but they do form a springboard from which we can **launch** **our own ideas**
>   about succession planning
>   Here is the link.

[For project safety back up your people, not just your data](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/passing-baton-succession-planning-foss-leadership)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does mean that in the text.

This is the kind of business speak where the author tries to sound eloquent but to me this style is just posturing, grandstanding. One can *launch* a boat for the first time, or send a rocket into space. These are grand events. Later, these positive associations have been exploited by marketers repurposing the word *launch* to make the introduction of their products look significant. In your context, they don't even do this, it's basically just brainstorming what the author means: we'll throw around ideas relying on the framework found in the existing literature.